# Complex object deserialization java

Tags: java, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an XML string to an object that has a list inside. The deserialization is partially successful. These are my java classes.

```
public class Vector {
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;
}

public class TP{
    public Date Time;
    public double thrust;
    public double isp;
    public double duration = .5;
    public Vector direction;
}

public class SOP{
    public Date Time;
    public Vector Position;
    public Vector Velocity;
    public Vector Acceleration;
    public double mass;
}

@XmlRootElement(name="OPS")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OPS{

    public OPS() {
        TPS= new ArrayList<TP>();
    }
    
    public SOP initialState;
    public List<TP> TPS;
    public Date Time;
    
}
```

This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OPS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <initialState>
    <Time>2021-03-18T09:55:07.1259143-04:00</Time>
    <Position>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <z>0</z>
    </Position>
    <Velocity>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <z>0</z>
    </Velocity>
    <Acceleration>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <z>0</z>
    </Acceleration>
    <mass>0</mass>
  </initialState>
  <TPS>
    <TP>
      <Time>2021-03-18T09:55:07.1119203-04:00</Time>
      <thrust>1</thrust>
      <isp>1</isp>
      <duration>0.5</duration>
      <direction>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <z>0</z>
      </direction>
    </TP>
    <TP>
      <Time>2021-03-18T09:55:07.1259143-04:00</Time>
      <thrust>1</thrust>
      <isp>1</isp>
      <duration>0.5</duration>
      <direction>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <z>0</z>
      </direction>
    </TP>
    <TP>
      <Time>2021-03-18T09:55:07.1259143-04:00</Time>
      <thrust>1</thrust>
      <isp>1</isp>
      <duration>0.5</duration>
      <direction>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <z>0</z>
      </direction>
    </TP>
  </TPS>
  <Time>2021-03-18T09:55:07.1259143-04:00</Time>
</OPS
```

After deserializing, the OPS object will have data on the Time and initialState properties, but the TPS list is null. What am I missing? Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Your deserialization logic? Is it raw deserialization? Or using Jackson?

Comment: Raw deserialization.

Comment: Can you share ThrustParams class's implementation?

Comment: it was supposed to be:TPS= new ArrayList<TP>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the TPS property add **@XmlElementWrapper** and **@XmlElement** annotations:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="OPS")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class OPS {

        public OPS() {
            TPS= new ArrayList<TP>();
        }

        public SOP initialState;
        @XmlElementWrapper(name="TPS")
        @XmlElement(name="TP")
        public List<TP> TPS;
        public Date Time;
```

More can find details here: [JAXB & Collection Properties](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html)